# Elastic search is not pulling count as mentioned sometimes

Tags: elasticsearch, count, mismatch

We are using elastic search and 70% of the time it is working as expected, There are empty rows being added to the grid as the count from elastic search does not match the count in grid. I can confirm the data is there and the issue is with pulling the data, does anyone saw this issue with elastic search

pulling the count differently everytime

Comment: Can you share the query?